# Finding surface area of a curve $x=t^3$,$ y=t^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the surface area of a curve rotated about the x axis, with $x=t^3$ and $y=t^2$. I have $$s=2\pi\int t^2\sqrt{r^2(3t^2)^2+r^2(2t)^2}$$ then $$=2\pi r\int t^2\sqrt{9t^4+4t^2}$$ I tried pulling out some **t**s and doing a u substitution for the rest of the inside of the square root section but I couldn't get it to where all the **t**s canceled out to leave just u.

Comment: You can still factor out a $t^2$ from under the radical and write your integral as $2\pi r\int t^3 \sqrt{9t^2+4}\,dt$; now do a "total" $u$-substitution ($u=9t^2+4$).

Comment: And then you'd wind up with $\frac{\int t^3\sqrt{u}du}{18t}$ which would only cancel out one of the ts on top.

Comment: Then use the fact that $\displaystyle t^2={u-4\over 9}$ to get rid of that last $t^2$.

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I really need to get better at seeing things like that you can do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's why you're given practice problems. 8-)